# symfony many to many orm controller

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I have a many-to-many relationship this is my table

```
site
------
id
name


site_landingpage
---------------
id
site_id
landingpage_id


landingpage
----------
id
name


Page.php
-----------------------
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Page\DefaultBundle\Entity\Site", mappedBy="landingpages")
**/
    private $sites;


Site.php
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Site\PageBundle\Entity\Page", inversedBy="sites")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="site_landingpage")
     **/

    private $landingpage;
```

If I add a landingpage it should get the current site and populate site_landingpage table how am I able to do this in the controller part where you add a landingpage given that my site_id is $site_id

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your entities have their getters & setters created, if not generate them by running:

```
app/console doctrine:generate:entities PageBundle:Site
app/console doctrine:generate:entities PageBundle:Page
```

Then you can simply do something like:

```
$landingpage = new Page();
$site->addLandingpage($landingpage);
```

[This blog post](http://www.keithwatanabe.net/2013/10/17/symfony-2-many-to-many-relationships-and-form-elements/) by Kontroversial Keith provides a detailed example of populating many-to-many relationship entities from user input.

As a side note, join tables (ie site_landingpage) don't need an extra `id` column (although shouldn't break anything), simply have site_id & landingpage_id as a joint primarykey.

Comment: what is the value of $site? in $site->addLandingpage($landingpage);
also the problem is I don't have access to ssh of the server and downloading the files will reach about 2gb

Comment: $site is the Site doctrine entity which you will presumably have already created or retrieved from the database. If you don't have access to the command line then you could run the commands locally then upload. Basically you should have a load of functions in your entity file like addLandingpage(Site $site);